# Cookie not being set on browser, even though the entry is created in the database - GraphQL, ApolloServer, MongoDB, Express

Tags: express, graphql, session-cookies, apollo-server

I am building a project and want to store the session's data in MongoDB with the help of ApolloServer, Express, GraphQL
However, I am unable to set the cookie on the browser (Chrome & Firefox)
Initially, I had a few CORS errors, I believe I fixed them
The session data and ID are being stored in MongoDB successfully
When I log in and run the "me" query to check if the cookie was set, it returns null as in nothing was set
Please help me

*index.js*

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import express from "express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import mikroOrmConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";
import { HelloResolver } from "./resolvers/hello";
import { PostResolver } from "./resolvers/post";
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { MyContext } from "./types";


const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(mikroOrmConfig);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

  const app = express();

  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://studio.apollographql.com',
    credentials: true
  }

  app.set("trust proxy", 1);
  

  app.use(
    session({
      name: "qid",
      secret: "secret",
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,
      store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: "mongodb://localhost/test-app",
        touchAfter: 24 * 3600, // time period in seconds
      }),
      cookie: {
          maxAge: 3600 * 60 *30 * 24 * 3600,
          secure: true,
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: 'lax'
      }
    })
  );

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver, UserResolver],
      validate: false,
    }),
 
    context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em.fork(), req, res }),
  });

  await apolloServer.start();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("server started on port 4000");
  });
};
```

*package.json*

```
 "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/connect-mongo": "^3.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^4.5.9",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.3.0",
    "argon2": "^0.28.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "configPaths": [
      "./sr/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
```

*user.ts* **login Mutation**

```
@Mutation(() => UserResponse)
  async login(
    @Arg("options", () => UsernamePasswordInput) options: UsernamePasswordInput,
    @Ctx() { em, req }: MyContext
  ): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const user = await em.findOne(User, { username: options.username });
    if (!user) {
      return {
        errors: [
          {
            field: "username",
            message: "Invalid Username",
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password, options.password);

    if (!valid) {
      return {
        errors: [
          {
            field: "password",
            message: "Invalid Password",
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    req.session.userId = user.id;

    return {
      user,
    };
  }
```

*user.ts* **me Query**

```
@Query(() => User, {nullable: true})
    async me(
      @Ctx() { req, em }: MyContext,
    ){
      if(!req.session.userId){
        return null;
      }
      else {
        const user = await em.findOne(User, { id: req.session.userId });
        return user;
      }
    }
```

*The context*

```
import { EntityManager, IDatabaseDriver, Connection } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { Session } from 'express-session';

export interface MyContext {
    em: EntityManager<any> & EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>;
    req: Request & { session?: Session & { userId?: number }};
    res: Response;
};
```

[Session data getting stored in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbCr2.png)

[ApolloGraphQL, the user is null even after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8cqz.png)

Please help me or give me some pointers if I have made any mistakes, Thank You!

Comment: You are setting the cookie on the server and trying to access it on the browser, right?

Comment: @Ammar Yes, when logging in, a cookie is created and that is visible in the database, but when I'm querying it on the browser it seems to have been disappeared

Comment: You can not access HttpOnly cookies inside the browser. Please try passing **httpOnly: false** inside your cookie object. Also, verify it by manually checking the cookie in your browser.

Comment: @Ammar The *me query* still outputs **null** even after login :(